# error 404 while run springBoot application on chrome browser

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

> I want to use jsp with springboot, i add jasper dependency in my
> pom.xml file, but when i run my springboot app it run corectly ,when i
> type localhost:8080/home in my browser it show me this type of error.
> i use getMapping annotation in palace of RequestMapping,I try it last
> four days but it cannot shorout

[image]

> this is my project file strcture
> [image]

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurityTutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringSecurityTutorial</name>
    <description>Spring Security Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.35</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> HomeConteoller.java

```
package com.main.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        
        return "Home.jsp";
    }

}
```

> home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  Welcome to Security Protection
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string returned by the `home()` handler method in your controller should be the name of the JSP view, without the extension. i.e. `return "home";`.

Comment: I use this trick but I get same error.I want retain my jsp page

Comment: Actually, it seems that using JSP with Spring Boot is a little more complicated. It needs to be packaged as a war since "JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar." 

More documentation and a sample project [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.16.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the following dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

return "/Home.jsp";